# How to disable subtitles by default (but keep them available)?

Tags: vlc-media-player

When I play a video in VLC it always starts with subtitles! I don't want this! I want subtitles OFF until I *choose* to turn them ON.

I tried unchecking 'enable sub-pictures' in the preferences menu, but this removed the subtitle user interface entirely, making it difficult to get subtitles on the occasions I really do want them (foreign films).

Comment: This seems to be the default now in VLC 3. 0 and above. Finally they got it right....

Comment: Not what is being asked, but (in Ubuntu): `v` to cycle subtitle track, and `shift-v` to toggle subtitles.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I know this is kind of an old thread, but if someone else is looking for the answer, I found an easier way.

In the *simple* settings menu, go to "Subtitles/OSD" and under "Preferred Subtitle Language," enter `none`.  Subtitles will no longer be displayed unless you ask for them!  This works in VLC 2.2.1 and 2.2.4 (windows 7 and 10 respectively) for sure, and probably others too, but I have not tested it beyond those two.

Hey VLC guys, how about just making the default `none`, so we don't have to do this?  Pretty please??

Comment: This is BY FAR easier than all the other suggestions above and works like a charm, I'm on version 2.2.4 weatherwax with macOS. Please, upvote this answer for more attention.

Comment: Preferred language option is no longer there in the latest version 3.0.4

Comment: Option has been moved to Input/Codecs > 'subtitle language'

Comment: Works on macOS too with latest VLC 3.0.8

Comment: Works on macOS Version 3.0.17.3 Vetinari (Intel 64bit)

Comment: Works on macOS Ventura 13.2.1 with VLC 3.0.18 Vetinari.

Comment: Works on macOS 11.2, VLC 3.0.18 Vetinari.

Answer (score 84):

1. Browse to the menu Tools / Preferences / (Show settings: All) / Input/Codecs
2. Then set 'Subtitles Track ID' to 0

[image]

per http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=62294

Comment: +1 Warning to others, there's also an option just above `Subtitles Track ID` called just `Subtitles Track` that won't work. What a complicated way do disable something that should be disabled by default. I mean really, how often does the average person actually want their native language subtitled?

Comment: wow so obvious how did I miss that ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Completely unintuitive.

Comment: They totally need to make this more prominent and simpler. Also it should default to off - most people don't want subtitles on.

Comment: Also, you need to click the "Show All" settings button to find these preferences.

Comment: `-1` is used to disable subtitles

Comment: @user25 `-1` is the default setting, and subtitles are very definitely enabled when set to that.

Comment: @jmbpiano did you test it?

Comment: @user25 Yes. Multiple times, switching it back and forth between `0` and `-1`. Set to `0`, subtitles are not displayed by default. Set to `-1`, they are.

Comment: I do not recommend this. There is a much much easier solution here: https://superuser.com/a/1219880/169409

Answer (score 20):

Setting it to 0 doesn't always work. It works about 50% of the time. I set mine to 99 which seems to work better ;-)

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did. Thank you.

Comment: Same here - accepted answer didn't work; this one did.

Comment: `-1` is used to disable subtitles (or any other track)

Comment: This is what worked for me. Setting to "none" or setting track ID to 0 didn't. **Thank you!**

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to say that you can do this using the "simple" options as well: it's tools / preferences / and then "subtitles/OSD" which is the 4th big button on the left of the preferences menu, right above "input/codecs."

Then just uncheck "enable subtitles," the subtitles will remain available anytime via r-click/subtitles.

Also, after doing this, then switching to "show settings: all" in the lower left, the "subtitles track ID" that Colonel Panic suggests, is set to -1, not 0, which could be why some folks are having trouble with it. You can manually set this to -1, to achieve the same result. Cheerio!

Comment: The question clearly says they don't want to disable subtitles, they want them off by default. Also -1 does *NOT* disable subtitles it makes the subtitles go to the default language.

Answer (score 2):

This answer corresponds to `VLC 3.0.4 Vetinari` on an ubuntu system. The subtitles can be disabled by unchecking `Enable Subtitles` on `Tools-->Preferences-->Subtitles/OSD` screen.

It can be enabled by pressing `v` during the running of video.

Screenshot below

[image]